# Activities section missing when I upload to Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm facing a problem when try to send notification to user in Teams.
When I upload app to Teams, activities section in file manifest is missing.
So I can not send notification.

Here is manifest

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.11",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "id",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        ...
    },
    "icons": {
        ...
    },
    "name": {
        ...
    },
    "description": {
        ...
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "configurableTabs": [
        ...
    ],
    "staticTabs": [
        ...
    ],
    "permissions": [
        ...
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        ...
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        ...
    },
    "activities": {
        "activityTypes": [
            {
                "type": "taskCreated",
                "description": "Task created activity",
                "templateText": "hah created task hehe for you"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you please refer below doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications

Comment: We have tested this using App studio. We have imported manifest zip via App studio in Teams. The activities section is missing from app manifest.
We have raised a bug for it. We will inform you once we have any updates

Answer (score 0):

App Studio doesn't support Activities.  Please use Developer Portal instead, which supports all the latest features.